# spring callable not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement long polling using spring,here is the sample code

Here is the code for my async method:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "failed.html" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected  Callable<String> callable(@ModelAttribute("user") Message user1, BindingResult bindingResult){
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("call--------->");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return "success";
        }
    };
    }
```

Here is the callablecontroller-servlet.xml:

```
<beans 
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">



<bean id= "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value></value></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>     

<bean id="callable" class="spring.controller.CallableController">
</bean>
```

However "call------------" is never printed in the console and it displays failed.jsp instead of success.jsp. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can show where "failed.jsp" is mentioned in your source, that would help. Is it in some exception handler ?

Comment: @vendhan thanks for the support i solved the  problem, i missed to set enable asynchronous support of the controller

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion is about the arguments to the callable method. 
Try adding a ExceptionHandler to your controller class as follows, to know whats going wrong:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
public String handleException(IllegalStateException ex) {
  System.out.println("Exception --------->");
  return "Handled exception: " + ex.getMessage();
}
```